1970s TV show - Two children find a barrow containing King Arthur
A live action TV show in which two children find a barrow containing King Arthur or some other sleeping knight. That's all I remember about the entire show I'm afraid, that and being mesmerised by it

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Do you remember if the kids went into the barrow?  Did they see Arthur?  Was his body there, was it alive, or was his spirit there?

Hi David. Thanks for the response. I think I've found it. According to Chat GPT there's a story in The Flaxton Boys (1969) that includes a sleeping knight found in a barrow at the end of series one. I just need to find a way to watch it now to confirm :-)

I would take anything that ChatGPT tells you with a very large grain of salt.  It creates text that is coherent, but not necessarily correct.  The Wikipedia page for the show doesn't mention this particularly.

Are you sure that it's King Arthur? I'm thinking of "The Changes" tv series, broadcast in 1975; which was based on the books by Peter Dickinson. The character in the barrow was Merlin. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEoIHHgeyFAxXbWEEAHfXWAfoQFnoECDoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FThe_Changes_(TV_series)&usg=AOvVaw0uXIWNpaABp7nOONHaT1-0&opi=89978449

Are you sure that this was as long ago as the 1970s? I seem to remember that finding King Arthur in a barrow was one of the plot elements in Earthfasts but that was released in 1994.
